# Hive - pull the data for first and last records based on collection time

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

I have a hive table in which we are getting data per day with collection time (unix timestamp)

```
+--------+-----------------+------+----------+
| ticket | collection_time | type |   day    |
+--------+-----------------+------+----------+
| t1     |             123 | auto | 20170302 |
| t2     |             234 | req  | 20170302 |
| t3     |             345 | req  | 20170302 |
| t4     |             678 | auto | 20170303 |
| t5     |             111 | req  | 20170301 |
| t6     |             222 | auto | 20170301 |
| t7     |             333 | auto | 20170301 |
| t8     |             444 | req  | 20170301 |
+--------+-----------------+------+----------+
```

I want to find the total count of tickets on a day and (collection time and type) of ticket happening at first collection time and last collection time of a day. Please suggest any way to solve this problem using hive query.

```
+---------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------+----------+
| count(ticket) | first_tkt_coll_time | first_tkt_type | last_tkt_coll_time | last_tkt_type |   day    |
+---------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------+----------+
|             3 |                 123 | auto           |                345 | req20170302   |          |
|             1 |                 678 | auto           |                678 | auto          | 20170303 |
|             4 |                 111 | req            |                444 | req           | 20170301 |
+---------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+---------------+----------+
```

And we need to feed the count(ticket) for next day also in the same output set.

```
+---------+-------------+-----------------+------+-----------------+------+---‌​--+ 
| cnt_day | cnt_nxt_day | collection_time | type | collection_time | type | day | 
+---------+-------------+-----------------+------+-----------------+------+---‌​--+ 
| 4 | 3| 111 | req | 444 | req | 20170301 |
| 3 | 1| 123 | auto | 345 | req | 20170302 | 
| 1 | - | 678 | auto | 678 | auto | 20170303 | 
+---------+-------------+-----------------+------+-----------------+------+---‌​--+
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  cnt
       ,cnt_next_day 
       ,min_val.collection_time
       ,min_val.type
       ,max_val.collection_time
       ,max_val.type
       ,day

from   (select    count(*)                                                         as cnt
                 ,lead (count(*)) over (order by day)                              as cnt_next_day
                 ,min(named_struct('collection_time',collection_time,'type',type)) as min_val
                 ,max(named_struct('collection_time',collection_time,'type',type)) as max_val
                 ,day

        from      mytable

        group by  day
        ) t
```

---

```
+-----+--------------+-----------------+------+-----------------+------+----------+
| cnt | cnt_next_day | collection_time | type | collection_time | type |   day    |
+-----+--------------+-----------------+------+-----------------+------+----------+
|   4 | 3            |             111 | req  |             444 | req  | 20170301 |
|   3 | 1            |             123 | auto |             345 | req  | 20170302 |
|   1 | NULL         |             678 | auto |             678 | auto | 20170303 |
+-----+--------------+-----------------+------+-----------------+------+----------+
```

Comment: Is there a way we can find the count(ticket) for day + 1 for each day

+-----+-----------------+------+-----------------+------+----------+
| cnt_day | cnt_nxt_day collection_time | type | collection_time | type |   day    |
+-----+-----------------+------+-----------------+------+----------+
|   4 | 3|            111 | req  |             444 | req  | 20170301 |
|   3 | 1|         123 | auto |             345 | req  | 20170302 |
|   1 | - |          678 | auto |             678 | auto | 20170303 |
+-----+-----------------+------+-----------------+------+----------+

Comment: Please add it to your post (mark the text and use ctrl+k to change to code format)

Comment: Running below query to find the count for next day and getting error:
FAILED: ParseException line 1:48 missing FROM at '(' near '(' in subquery source
line 1:49 cannot recognize input near 'order' 'by' 'day' in subquery source

select count(*) as cnt_day, lead(count(*)) over (order by day) as cnt_nxt_day, day from fact_vreclass_tickets where day='20160301' group by day;

Comment: This is a tested code. What version of Hive are you using (`hive --version`)?

Comment: Hive version - hive-0.10.0

Comment: Windows/Analytic functions were added at 0.11 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-LEADusingdefault1rowleadandnotspecifyingdefaultvalue 0.10 was released at January 2013(!)